# Make an object from a partial specialized template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I create the object marked as WRONG? It is a partial specialized template class.

```
template<typename C, typename size_type = unsigned short>
struct MatrixDataRect {...};

template<typename T, size_t H, size_t W>
class MatrixDataRect<std::array<T,H*W>, size_t> {...};

int main()
{
    MatrixDataRect<std::vector<double>> mat_data_vector;
    MatrixDataRect<std::array<double,10*5>> mat_data_array; // WRONG!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

It is wrong because WRONG line uses first template class. Not second.
Because compiler cannot assign 10*5 to H and W respectively.

Comment: Why it is wrong? (It's OK in my GCC)

Comment: OK on my gcc as well!

Comment: @MM.: I imagine that *wrong* for him means that it won't instantiate the specialization

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename T, size_t H, size_t W>
class MatrixDataRect<std::array<T,H*W>, size_t> {...};
MatrixDataRect<std::array<double,10*5>> mat_data_array;
```

The problem is that the template arguments H and W cannot be deduced from the place of call. Basically, during the instantiation, the copiler will multiply `5*10` to yield `50` and then try to instantiate `std::array<double,50>`, the instantiated type is then used to instantiate `MatrixDataRect<std::array<double,50>>`. At this point it is impossible to figure out what the values of `H` and `W` are for the `MatrixDataRect` (is it 5 and 10?, 10 and 5?, 25 and 2?...)

Since type deduction cannot be applied, the compiler will fall back to the non-specialized version and instantiate the main template.

The alternatives you can use are: make the specialization take an `std::array` and a single size argument (as the main template). That works for all the code in the question, maybe not for other members if you need the two dimensions. Change the template so that the sizes are explicitly passed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. `10*5` is evaluated to 50 and then the compiler attempts to deduce `H*W` which cannot be done. They could be any `size_t` values that multiply to make 50.
2. You are specializing for `size_t` as the second template argument, which must be given when you instantiate it as it cannot be deduced. Otherwise you're just instantiating a `MatrixDataRect<std::array<double,10*5>, unsigned short>`.

The following would work:

```
template<typename C, typename size_type = unsigned short>
struct MatrixDataRect {...};

template<typename T, size_t S>
class MatrixDataRect<std::array<T,S>, size_t> {...};

int main()
{
    MatrixDataRect<std::vector<double>> mat_data_vector;
    MatrixDataRect<std::array<double,10*5>, size_t> mat_data_array;
    return 0;
}
```